# Validation last name error in checkout cart

Tags: checkout, php-5.4, validation

I have a problem with the checkout cart page in magento. In the checkout form I have included a last name input field to enable the Lastname validation.

```
<div class="field">
    <label>Nachname: *</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" required name="user[lastname]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getLastname()) ?>"  />
</div>
```

The validation works and I see the error messages if I try to pass an empty field, however when I type some text e.g. "test" in the field I always get the same error messages

This is the validation code from Page.php

```
public function validateAddress(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{
    $errors = array();
    $helper = Mage::helper('customer');
    $address->implodeStreetAddress();
    if (!Zend_Validate::is($address->getFirstname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = $helper->__('Please enter the first name.');
    }


    if (!Zend_Validate::is($address->getLastname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = $helper->__('Please enter the last name.');
    }

...
```

> "Please enter the last name."
>   I also tried with id="billing:lastname" name="billing[lastname]", but no luck.

Comment: Add relevant code from `Page.php`.